Spring Boot test error java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java
In my Spring Boot application I use this AWS paramstore and mentioned them in the application.properties file. Similarly for unit testing, that is especially for integration testing that is for controller class alone. I got the below errors. How to solve them or is it possible to disable the aws param in my unit testing alone? If yes, how to do that?
AsymmetricKeyOperationControllerTest > testRsaWithExpiredToken() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180
        Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException at ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException.java:97
            Caused by: io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.config.parameterstore.ParameterStorePropertySources$AwsParameterPropertySourceNotFoundException at ParameterStorePropertySources.java:53
                Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssm.model.SsmException at CombinedResponseHandler.java:125


id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.5'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
java {
- sourceCompatibility = '21'
}

I tried to solve them by adding
> Disable AWS Parameter Store for tests
> spring.config.import=optional:aws-parameterstore:/disabled

in the test/resources/application-test.properties file. This didn't help.
